# Prove complete graph $K_n$ can be decomposed into $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ paths or $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ cycles when $n$ is odd.

Tags: graph-theory

It's an exercise $5.3.48$ in textbook **Combinatorial Mathematics** by Douglas B. West.

First I observe that $$|E(K_n)| = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$ Then if $n$ is even, the average path length is $n-1$; if $n$ is odd, the average cycle length is $n$. By symmetry of $K_n$, I guess every path length is $n-1$ and every cycle length is $n$. And I am stuck there.

These results are first proved by Haj$\acute{o}$s and Gallai. But I can't find the original proof.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov Yes, they are separate tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of these decompositions can be done by drawing the vertices around a circle, and rotating copies of the same path or cycle.

For example, here is a decomposition of $K_8$ into four copies of $P_8$ (which is not one of the things you asked for, but is well-known):

[image]

We can add a $9^{\text{th}}$ vertex and join it to both ends of each path to get a decomposition of $K_9$ into four copies of $C_9$:

[image]

This can be generalized to decompose $K_{2k+1}$ into $k$ copies of $C_{2k+1}$.

Decomposing $K_{2k+1}$ into $k+1$ paths is trickier to do symmetrically, because then the average length is $\frac{2k^2+k}{k+1} = 2k-1 + \frac1{k+1}$; they can't all be the same length. It's possible to take the cycle decomposition above and peel an edge off of each cycle to get a short path: this gives $k$ copies of $P_{2k+1}$ (with $2k$ edges each) and one copy of $P_{k+1}$ (with $k$ edges).

Comment: @ Misha Lavrov Nice proof!